# Meteor: I'm having trouble searching a collection and returning the results. Exception while invoking method. not defined

Tags: javascript, mongodb, search, meteor, meteor-methods

I have a collection with a list of items called "categories" each category has an _id and a name field. I'm trying to simply return a search of the name of the category

here is the document structure. Each list item has these properties. Im trying to target the 'name' field  but i'm getting the error

[image]

#### I20160704-22:47:42.976(1)? Exception while invoking method 'findCategory' ReferenceError: id is not defined

client/html

```
 <form class="form-inline">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchCategory" placeholder="Search for Category">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Search</button>
</form>



 {{#if foundCategory}}
      <div class="foundCategory">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="follow">Follow @{{foundCategory.name}}</button>
      </div>
    {{/if}}
    </template>
```

server/js

```
Meteor.methods({
  'findCategory': function(name) {
    return Meteor.CategoryCollection.findOne({
      _id: id          
}, {
      fields: { 'name': 1 }
    });
  }
});
```

i tried

```
Meteor.methods({
      'findCategory': function(name) {
        return CategoryCollection.findOne({
          name : name         
    }, {
          fields: { 'name': 1 }
        });
      }
    });
```

but i get the error.

#### Exception while invoking method 'findCategory' TypeError: Cannot call method 'findOne' of undefined

How can i return the document i need?

**EDIT**

Im using [rest2ddp](https://atmospherejs.com/newspring/rest2ddp) to call the json data and inset it into CategoryCollection

i also changed Meteor.CategoryCollection to simply CategoryCollection

server/main.js

```
REST2DDP.publish("CategoryPublication", {
  collectionName: "CategoryCollection",
  restUrl: "http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/categories",
  jsonPath: "$.*",
  pollInterval: 5000,
});
```

client.subscriptions.js

```
CategoryCollection = new Mongo.Collection("CategoryCollection");
Meteor.subscribe("CategoryPublication");
Tracker.autorun(function () {
  console.log(CategoryCollection.find().fetch());
});
```

Comment: where and how do you define `CategoryCollection`? `Meteor.CategoryCollection` is almost certainly wrong (because you really shouldn't extend the Meteor object with your own variables.

Comment: Thank you for responding @ChristianFritz , Meteor.CategoryCollection was a typo on my part. in terms of where i defined CategoryCollection, i have edited the post to show this. I wonder if this is what you are asking. Please take a look.

Comment: Keith's answer below is correct. You need to define the collection server side as well, not just on the client. Just move that line into a file that is shared by client and server.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define

```
CategoryCollection = new Mongo.Collection("CategoryCollection");
```

server side and client side.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically looking for "**id**" where "**id**" has not been defined.

Try passing the document's "**id**" to the method if you have it available:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'findCategory': function(id, name) {
    return Meteor.CategoryCollection.findOne({
      _id: id          
}, {
      fields: { 'name': name }
    });
  }
});
```

If you are looking to find **fields: { 'name': 1 }** in any document then omit the first object **{ _id: id }** section.

```
Meteor.methods({
      'findCategory': function(name) {
        return Meteor.CategoryCollection.findOne({
          fields: { 'name': name }
        });
      }
    });
```